# render HTML conditionally on device

Tags: javascript, html, mobile-safari

```
<script>
    var isSafari = /^((?!chrome|android|crios|fxios).)*safari/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
    //check if device is mobile
    var isMobile = (/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|ipad|iris|kindle|Android|Silk|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i.test(navigator.userAgent) 
                                    || /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(navigator.userAgent.substr(0,4)));
    function writeHTMLasJS() {
    document.write("<div class=\"dy_app_wrapper_app\">");
document.write(" ");
document.write("    <div class=\"dy_logo_app\">");
document.write("      <div class=\"dy_x_app\"><\/div>");
document.write("       <a class=\"dy_link_app\" href=\"${Button Link}\"><img src=\"${logo url}\"><\/a>");
document.write("    <\/div>");
document.write("   ");
document.write("    <div class=\"dy_info_app\">");
document.write("      <div class=\"dy_text_app\">");
document.write("        Some Placeholder Text");
document.write("      <\/div>");
document.write("      <div class=\"dy-stars-open-container_app\">");
document.write("        <div class=\"dy_stars_app\">");
document.write("          <span class=\"dy_num_of_rankers_app\">");
document.write("            ${Number Of Rankers}");
document.write("          <\/span>");
document.write("        <\/div>");
document.write("        <div class=\"dy_button_app\">");
document.write("          <a class=\"dy_link_app\" href=\"${Button Link}\">${Button Text}<\/a>");
document.write("        <\/div>");
document.write("      <\/div>");
document.write("    <\/div>");
document.write("<\/div>");
    }
</script>


<script>
  console.log("point 1");
if (!isMobile) {
    console.log("this is a mobile browser");
    console.log(isSafari);
    if (!isSafari) {
        console.log("this is not safari");
    writeHTMLasJS();
    } else {
        console.log("this is safari");
    }
 } else {
 console.log("this is not a mobile browser");
 }
</script>
```

hey guys, so this is what I am trying to implement. The code above is supposed to if the device is a mobile and render the html on all browsers apart from SafariBrowser. It is not working for some reason. I'd appreciate any help

Comment: *Please* don't use `document.write`.

Answer (score 0):

document.write() writes the specified string on html file, not renders it. use PHP for device specific rendering or specify different html files for different devices and load the respective one when you meet the device requirements.